# How to prevent .action URL for iFrame inside modal causing whole page redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, struts2

I have a Bootstrap modal that is opened on a button click. Inside the modal, I have an iFrame with the src attribute equal to a URL that ends in .action (Struts2 framework). I am having the issue of on page load, the whole page is redirected to that URL. I have tried dynamically adding the iFrame src attribute when the button is clicked. This temporarily opens the modal, with nothing showing, and then redirects the whole page to that URL.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening, and instead having that URL displayed inside the iFrame in the modal, and only when the modal is opened?

I am using AngularJS if that matters at all.

Here is the code for the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe ng-src="https://mylink.action" width="600px" height="400px"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It should not happen at all. Please share your code

Comment: Added my code @AndreaLigios

Comment: Does it work if you hardcode your action link in iframe's `src` attribute, bypassing  angular's `ng-src` ? If yes, then you must investigate your angular code, if not, there's something really strange going on

Comment: That did not fix it. After troubleshooting it, it looks like the URL has a script in it that causes a redirect in the parent URL. I can prevent it via the sandbox attribute on the iframe. However, it looks like the scripts in the URL are not accounting for a redirect on the parent not working, so it still doesn't show up, but that is something I can work with. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: LOL :D I swear to God I was adding in my comment "The only remaining explanation would be that the page loaded has a script to redirect the parent", but then I've thought that it seemed sci-fi, because in that case you should have known it, and I've omitted it... well, never say never! :D